# C# Unload temp Appdomain while main Appdomain uses MethodInfo from temp

Tags: c#, assembly, dll, appdomain

I want to make a reloadable assembly function for scripting.(So i can debug scripts quicker)

The dll generation works and loading too. The main problem is, that I`m using the functions of my temporary AppDomain in my main AppDomain. The dll seems to be linked to my main AppDomain too, because I cant delete it while the program is running.
If I remove all MethodInfo references from my main AppDomain "context" then I have no problems deleting it.

Here you can see how the program works:

- Generate DLL from external process
- Load DLL by (temp AppDomain).DoCallBack(...)
- Get Type & MethodInfo and call it.
- AppDomain.Unload(temp AppDomain)

So if I skip step 3, I have no problems deleten the dll. But I cant check if the return of the Function really shows the updated value (which i edit inside the script).

I have posted the source code for each step here:
1.

```
//This actually isn`t as important for you    
Process assemblyGeneration = new Process();
    assemblyGeneration.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"lib\AssemblyCompiler.exe";
    assemblyGeneration.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "script.dll\" \"" + source + "\" \"System.dll\"";
    assemblyGeneration.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    assemblyGeneration.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    assemblyGeneration.Start();
    assemblyGeneration.WaitForExit();
    assemblyGeneration.Dispose();
```

2.

```
        _appDomain.DoCallBack(() =>
        {
            byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "script.dll");
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(fileContent);
        });
```

3.

```
MethodInfo info = _compiledScript.GetTypeFrom("LSCT.ScriptClass").GetMethod("DefineX");

        var func = (Func<double>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<double>), info);
        double x = func();
        Console.WriteLine("Output was : " + x);
```

4.

```
AppDomain.Unload(_appDomain);
```

So is there a way to work around the issue, that I cant reload the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem. Maybe there is a performance issue now but I have not checked it yet.

Anyways, I created a new class which inherit MarshalByRefObject and let it load from the temp AppDomain.

Here is the code for the new class:

```
public class ProcessRunner : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Type typ = null;
        foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Type t = asm.GetType("LSCT.ScriptClass");
            if (t != null)
            {
                typ = t;
                break;
            }
        }
        MethodInfo info = typ.GetMethod("DefineX");

        var func = (Func<double>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<double>), info);
        double x = func();
        Console.WriteLine("Output was : " + x);
    }
}
```

And here is how to invoke it from the temp AppDomain:

```
        ProcessRunner pr = (ProcessRunner)_appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "Animation_Engine.UserInterface.Code.ProcessRunner");
        pr.Run();
```

> Note: As soon as you pass any references from your main AppDomain (by
>   parameters for example) to the executing class, the dll will be linked to your main AppDomain
>   and is not able to unload until the main AppDomain ends.